# Vscode Extension how to grab values of variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Looked everywhere but unsure how to accomplish this feat. I'm looking to do something like this. When a user types something like this:

```
const hi = 'hello world';

#generate(hi)
```

and the user highlights #generate(hi), the user can run a set command. This command is written like this in the extension:

```
const generateCodeCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.generateCode', () => {
    const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;

    if (editor) {
        const document = editor.document;
        const selection = editor.selection;

        // get the word within the selection
        const word = document.getText(selection);
        console.log('this is the word', word);
    }
});
```

Here I've managed to grab the word '#generate(hi)' but I'm looking to grab the string 'hello world' through the 'hi' reference. Is there a particular way to do this?

Comment: create an AST of the file (or compile) and execute up to the selected text

Comment: do you know of any links/examples of this on how i can implement?